# Can`t run BlueTooth discovery from Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I can`t run startDiscovery (for BlueTooth) from Service.
Service run from sleep by *WakefulBroadcastReceiver* (by timer).
Source code of Service:

```
    public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate");

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
       filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
       filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
       registerReceiver(mBTReceiver, filter);
     }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        BTscanner();    
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (btAdapter != null) {
          btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       }
    unregisterReceiver(mBTReceiver);
    }

    private void BTscanner() {
       Log.e(TAG, "==BT: Run BTscanner");           
       btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       btAdapter.startDiscovery();
       Log.e(TAG, "==BT: End BTscanner");
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "==BT: Started");
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "==BT: Finished");
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            Log.e(TAG, "==BT: " + device.getAddress());
        }
    }

    };


 }
```

In log i see:

```
Service onStartCommand
==BT: Run BTscanner
==BT: End BTscanner
```

but don`t see:

```
==BT: Started
==BT: Finished
```

and list of discovered devices.

In *Manifest* all permissions installed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

and service enabled in application field of Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
```

What did I do wrong?
Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found a solution.

There were problems when I install and run the application with active Bluetooth on smartphone.

After installing application and manual deactivate/activate Bluetooth device all works fine.

Maybe it was some sort of a hardware failure.

Then reinstall the application twice, and the problem is not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your receiver has not been unregistered in the onDestroy method before having the time to handle any action? I would put a break point in it to see what's happenning in there?

Comment: I put a break point to all methods. Everything works normally.